# Copy the value next to the column that has 1, and paste it to multiple places in another sheet, looping through one by one

Tags: excel, vba, offset

The logic of my Macro is supposed to be:

I have 2 colums

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| DHBE | 1 |
| DHEU | 0 |
| SJER | 1 |

If in Column 2, there is a 1, then take the text from Column 1 and paste it into another tab/sheet.
e.g.

```
DHBE - copy & go to sheet("Template").select, Paste in Rows "I4:I549"
Select Range E4:R549.copy
sheet("Volume").select, Paste under last row, starting in column A

skip DHEU

SJER - copy & go to sheet("Template").select, Paste in Rows "I4:I549"
Select Range E4:R549.copy
sheet("Volume").select, Paste under last row, starting in column A
```

Question: The Macro loops through all the data in Column 1 at once, I would like it to loop through it one by one and copy it in a different tab/sheet in different columns?

```
Sub Config()  
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Sheets("Upload Config").Select
    
    tr = Columns(1).Rows.Count
    
    Set Rng1 = Range("B4:B" & tr)
    
    For Each c In Rng1
    
        If c.Value = "1" Then
        
            c.Offset(0, -1).Copy
            
            

            'Option 1

            'Destination:=Range("b" & tr).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            'Option 2

            Range("a32").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Also it is very unclear what you mean by *"into different parts of the workbook"*. Please [edit] and clarify. Give an example of your input data and what you expect as output. It is very unclear what the destination of your copied data should be.

Comment: Hello! You are so right! Please find the corrected version. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following which is much faster than copying each value:

First we load all data into an array because array processing is much faster than processing ranges. Then we check wich data needs to be in the output and collect it in a collection. Then we write he collected data into a 2 dimensional output array that can easily be written into a range:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Config()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload Config")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  ' get last used row in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim DataRange As Range  ' get data range A1:B3
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1", "B" & LastRow)
    
    Dim DataArray() As Variant  ' read data into an array (for fast processing)
    DataArray = DataRange.Value
    
    Dim OutputData As Collection  ' create a collection where we collect all desired data
    Set OutputData = New Collection
    
    ' check each data row and if desired add to collection
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(DataArray, 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1)
        If DataArray(iRow, 2) = 1 Then
            OutputData.Add DataArray(iRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    ' create an output array of the size of collected data
    Dim OutputArray() As Variant
    ReDim OutputArray(1 To OutputData.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    ' turn collection into an 2 dimensional array (that we can write to a range)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To OutputData.Count
        OutputArray(i, 1) = OutputData.Item(i)
    Next i
    
    ' write the array data to a range
    ws.Range("D1").Resize(RowSize:=OutputData.Count).Value = OutputArray
End Sub
```

The result will be written from D1 downwards.

[image]
<sub>*Image 1: Output data in red, input data in black.*</sub>

---

// edit

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Config()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload Config")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long  ' get last used row in column A
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim DataRange As Range  ' get data range A1:B3
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A1", "B" & LastRow)
    
    Dim DataArray() As Variant  ' read data into an array (for fast processing)
    DataArray = DataRange.Value
    
    Dim OutputData As Collection  ' create a collection where we collect all desired data
    Set OutputData = New Collection
    
    ' check each data row and if desired add to collection
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(DataArray, 1) To UBound(DataArray, 1)
        If DataArray(iRow, 2) = 1 Then
            OutputData.Add DataArray(iRow, 1)
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
    Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    
    Dim wsVolume As Worksheet
    Set wsVolume = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Volume")
    
    ' loop through your collection and do the copy stuff
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To OutputData.Count
        wsTemplate.Range("I4:I549").Value = OutputData.Item(i) ' write values DHBE, SJER
        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = wsTemplate.Range("E4:R549")
        
        ' copy values from source range to sheet volume last row
        wsVolume.Cells(wsVolume.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=SourceRange.Rows.Count, ColumnSize:=SourceRange.Columns.Count).Value = SourceRange.Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! Thank you so much! However this is too elaborate for what I need, I don't need to store them in the array, I need the data from column 1, copied, and then I need to paste it into another template, and then I need to take that template and paste is somewhere else. So for every text in columen 1, I need to do several copy paste things. and then I need to move onto the next row in column 1.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need to do several copy paste things"*. **what** exactly do you need to do? (you can edit your original question to add that information if a comment does not fit). If you need that output in another sheet you can just replace `ws.Range("D1")` with something like `Worksheets("SheetOutput").Range("E1")` and it will put it there.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the patience, I have added some points to the example.

Comment: @annabelle_123 ok that changese the entire question. See my edit. You just need to change the end of the code a bit then.

Comment: @peh Thank you so much! I managed to change the last row to copy paste all the column, however, the last row of data always gets overridden, and I don't know what to change! Help me pls..                                                                               
wsVolume.Cells(wsVolume.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(546, 14).Value = SourceRange.Value

Comment: use `Resize(RowSize:=SourceRange.Rows.Count, ColumnSize:=SourceRange.Columns.Count)`

Comment: @peh you are a star! Thank you so much for all your help, it still dosen't work thou.. The code still overrides the last row.

Comment: Then check the range you copy `E4:R549`. This needs to fit into the destination otherwise data gets overwritten. So this will write into `A1:N546`.

Comment: @peh, ah okay, I mean when I copy the first set of data into the VOLUME tab, I want it to start in row 2 and it keeps overriding row 1. I think it is the End(xlUp) command, it usually has a .row+1 behind it no? - I also have another question, where can I add that I would like to copy the formulas? not only the data?

Comment: Ah of course my fault, you need to `.Offset(RowOffset:=1)` additionally. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Thank you sooo so much @peh very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @PEH it has been two days and I cannot figure out how to change the last part of the code, to: Lookup the value in the array in sheet2 and return an offset value (4,0) to another sheet, one below the other. Could you maybe help me here again?

Comment: @annabelle_123 Please open up a new question for that where you can show what you have tried and provide a proper description of your issue. See [ask].